# BlackBerry JDE Eclipse install

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Installing BlackBerry's JDE in Eclipse, via Help > Install New Software, it fails with this error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.1.2.201004161203-16 (net.rim.EclipseJDE.feature.group 1.1.2.201004161203-16)
>   Missing requirement: BlackBerry Java Plug-in 1.1.2.201004161203-16 (net.rim.EclipseJDE.feature.group 1.1.2.201004161203-16) requires 'org.eclipse.help [3.4.0,3.5.0)' but it could not be found

Also;

I downloaded pluging(full installer) setup, but not it doesn't work. I work on win7, it says me Select another path for install, I tried everywhere... nothing changes.

**ITS OK. I DOWNLOADED eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32 version. I am downloadng content from blackberry now... But I have a problem about installing plugin manually.!!**

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact kind of problem.  Worked on it on and off for over a week.  Never got a good solution.  I noticed that when I did the install it was saying "blocking" and it would take several hours to do the install.  I tried it from work and from home.  It still took hours.  Most of the time it failed.  One time it finally worked (or seemed to), but there were missing menu options.  I suspect the error message is wrong.

Short answer, I've gotten marginal success using an alternate method of install.  Try this:
http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp

Click on "Download the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.1 (full installer)"

It seems to install correctly and MUCH quicker (on the order of a few minutes as opposed to hours), no error messages, no warning messages - and the expected menu items are there.

Good luck.

Note: I still have the problem that I can't get the damned applications to install on the phone even though they work in the simulator, but I'm reasonably confident it's not because the JDE installation failed.

Comment: Regarding my somewhat exasperated final note in the previous message, I have been able to get the app installed on the BB by using JavaLoader.exe to manually force the .cod file over to the phone.  This partly confirms that the method I outlined above correctly installed the plug-in.

Comment: I downloaded pluging(full installer) setup, but not it doesn't work. I work on win7, it says me Select another path for install, I tried everywhere... nothing changes.

Comment: Atasoyh, did you install Eclipse first and then install the JDE ontop of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
BlackBerry Java Plug-in ... requires 'org.eclipse.help [3.4.0,3.5.0)'
```

The key takeaway from the error message is that org.ecilpse.help is missing.  What do you know about org.eclipse.help?

Answer (score -1):

> **Use Eclipse to install the BlackBerry Java Plug-in.**

1. Choose `Help` > `Install New Software`.
2. Click `Add`.
3. For `Name`, type **BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site**.
4. For `Location`, type **http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/mac/java**.
5. Click `OK`.
6. Select `BlackBerry Java Plug-in` and at least one BlackBerry SDK. Choose the version of the BlackBerry SDK that is compatible with your intended target market.
7. Click `Next`.
8. Review the items being installed, and then click `Next`.
9. Review the license agreement, and then check `I accept the terms of the license agreement` if you agree.
10. Click `Finish` to begin the installation.
11. After the plug-in is updated, you'll be prompted to restart Eclipse.

Comment: This seems to be a cut/paste from the official BB documentation found here: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/.  Note that for windows the update URL is: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java.